# How can I upload picture

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

**This is my post dto**

```
  public class ActorDto
  {
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public string Surname { get; set; }
      public string ImdbLink { get; set; }
      public IFormFile Image { get; set; }

  }
```

**This is my entity**

```
    public class Actor
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string ImdbLink { get; set; }
        public string ImageURL { get; set; }
    }
```

and  my **actor controller .** here I want to receieve dto`s information and create actor entity.

```
 [HttpPost]
 public async Task<ActionResult<ActorDto>> CreateActor(ActorDto dto)
 {
     var actor = _mapper.Map<SeeN.Entities.Actor>(dto); // Map directly to entity

     var filename = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + Path.GetExtension(dto.Image.FileName);
     var imagePath = Path.Combine("wwwroot/Actor", filename);
     using (var stream = new FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Create))
     {
         await dto.Image.CopyToAsync(stream);
     }
     actor.ImageURL = filename;

     var imageBaseUrl = $"http://localhost:5212/Actor";
     dto.Image = imageBaseUrl + "/" + filename;

     _context.Actors.Add(actor); // Add to context 
     await _context.SaveChangesAsync();


     // Create ActorDto directly
     var actorDto = new ActorDto
     {
         Name = actor.Name,
         Surname = actor.Surname,
         ImdbLink = actor.ImdbLink,
         Image = actor.ImageURL
     };

     return Ok(actorDto);
 }
```

how can I convert string to IFromFile or what is the best way for this

Answer (score 0):

convert a file path string to an IFormFile object:

```
string filePath = "path_to_your_file.jpg"; // Replace with the actual file path

byte[] fileBytes = await File.ReadAllBytesAsync(filePath);

IFormFile formFile = new FormFile(new MemoryStream(fileBytes), 0, fileBytes.Length, "Image", Path.GetFileName(filePath));
```

Replace "path_to_your_file.jpg" with the actual file path

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your clients. If your client is a DotNet application, you can do it with the code below:

```
 using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent();

        formData.Add(new StringContent("John"), nameof(ActorDto.Name));
        formData.Add(new StringContent("Doe"), nameof(ActorDto.Surname));
        formData.Add(new StringContent("Imdb_link"), nameof(ActorDto.ImdbLink));

        // Replace this with the path to your image
        var filePath = @"path_to_the_actor_images\image.jpg";
        var imageContent = new ByteArrayContent(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath));
        imageContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("multipart/form-data");

        formData.Add(imageContent, nameof(ActorDto.Image), "actor.jpg");

        var response = await client.PostAsync("API_URL", formData);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(content);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Failed to upload. Status code: {response.StatusCode}");
        }
    }
```